# Behavior of text-align-last vs text-align on Select Tag

Tags: html, css

I tried centering the text of an `option` tag using `text-align:center` to no avail. Some research found me the solution of `text-align-last:center` and this worked but it doesn't make sense to me how? If both `text-align-last` and `text-align` are both are responsible for centering text, then shouldn't `text-align` on its own been able to do the job?

Heres a fiddle of what i'm talking about: https://jsfiddle.net/L3ehgc0j/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The text-align-last CSS property describes how the last line of a block or a line, right before a forced line break, is aligned.

And

The text-align CSS property describes how inline content like text is aligned in its parent block element. text-align does not control the alignment of block elements, only their inline content.

Comment: So if i tried setting the `display` prop of the `option` tag to `inline` would that make it suitable to be centered with `text-align`?

Comment: You want to center the option button inside the webpage?

Comment: no, i'm talking about the text inside the `select` box which come from the `option` tags. `option` tags are block elements so i tried making them inline elements and centering them but nothing happened.

Comment: I'm not sure if its possible using CSS but it is possible using a jQuery Plugin